# Can python 3.5 packages be installed in python 3.6?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I've built tensorflow using python 3.5, but when attempting to install it via pip3 (in python 3.6), it says

```
tensorflow-1.12.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

So, is this due to being incompatible python versions?

Bonus question: how can I get pip to tell me the reason for the incompatibility?

Comment: you need none-any wheels, or the exact python version & architecture.

Answer (score 1):

The package apparently has some compiled bits that may not be compatible across versions. The Python ABI may be different.

You can install pre-built tensorflow right from Pypi

```
$ pip3.6 install tensorflow
```

Will that work for you?

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, most pip packages should work, but tensorflow cant? I can't use prebuilt because modern versions of tensorflow require AVX and SSE4.x instructions that my machine don't have.

Comment: @mdsimmo Any pure-Python package should work. But if it has compiled (C language) modules or "helper" modules then it must be compiled for one specific version.